# "Manual" Factor Analysis in R

Tags: r, pca

I am trying to follow along the Factor Analysis chapter in "Using Multivariate Statistics", by Tabachnick and Fidell.

The data, and my steps, are as follows:

```
# data
dat.ski <- data.frame(skiers = paste0("S", c(1:5), sep=""), cost = c(32, 61, 59, 36, 62), lift=c(64, 37, 40, 62, 46) , depth = c(65, 62, 45, 34, 43), powder = c(67, 65, 43, 35, 40))

# correlation matrix
cor.ski <- cor(dplyr::select(dat.ski, -skiers)) 

# eigenvalues and eigenvectors
eig.ski <- eigen(cor.ski)
```

The correlation matrix and eigenvalues (2.02, 1.94, 0.04 and 0.00) correspond to that in the book. The first two eigenvectors I have are (.352, -0.251, -0.626, -0.647) and (.514, -.664, .322, .280).

However, the book then continues to say that only the first two eigenvalues are retained and the "factor analysis is re-run" which results in the following two eigenvalues*: 2.00, 1.91 and eigenvectors (-2,83, 0.177, 0.568, 0.675) and (0.651, -0.685, 0.252, 0.207).  I can't work out to reproduce these eigenvectors... if I run `psych::fa(cor.ski, nfactors=2, fm="pa")`, the SS loadings correspond to the new eigenvalues*.

Any help on how to return the eigenvectors as per the text will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I worked this out by remembering that R is a visible language!  By looking at the definition of `psych::fac`, I see that the authors have actually performed 7 iterations of factor analysis, not mereley "taken the first two eigenvectors and rerun FA"; I also finally understand how factor analysis is performed and can tie it in with the subsequent text, which in a nutshell is:

Starting with the correlation matrix (r) and assuming k factors are used

- Get eigenvalues (L) and eigenvectors (V) of correlation matrix r
- Calculate C = sum(diag(R))
- Calculate the loadings, A = V[,1:k] * Sqrt{L[1:k]}  (eqn 13.6 of text)
- set R* = AA'   (eqn 13.5 of text, R=AA')
- set C* = sum(diag(R*))
- Update diag(R) = diag(R*)
- Repeat above steps until max iterations reached, or until e = abs(C-C*) is smaller than some threshold

Comment: Were you able to reproduce your eigen vectors : `(-2,83, 0.177, 0.568, 0.675)`  and `(0.651, -0.685, 0.252, 0.207)` after reasonable iterations??

Comment: Yes, I extracted the relevant parts of the `psych::fac` function and stored the eigenvectors before it overwrote the list returned from the eigen function with the values only.

Comment: Good. Then you should probably complete your answer by providing the step wise code to achieve it. This will make your answer reproducible for the above question.